# How do I fix this module import circular dependency in a good coding practice way?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, refactoring

I have a shared module to export all shared components between other modules inside my app. However, I got this issue where my SharedModule (which imports and exports EditableModule) has to import DateRangePicker, BUUT DateRangePicker has to be also inside EditableModule therefore I have a circular dependency.

I fixed the dependency by adding DateRangePicker to both modules but I don't think is a good code practice.
Is there a way to fix this making it look pretty and professional?

EditableModule

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [ 
    Daterangepicker
    ],
    exports: [
        SomeComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent    
    ]
})
```

SharedModule

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
        Daterangepicker,
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    exports: [
        Daterangepicker,
    ]
})
```

Comment: You haven't described the circular path very well. Please include the circular warning message that is shown in the console.

Comment: I solved it using 2 Input forms instead of using an npm package.